# Cpanel image not showing

Tags: cpanel

I have the same issue again and again. I have uploaded a css background image and delete trash,cache in the cpanel,and the browser cache. But still display the image that I have deleted already.

Comment: Put your code in question for a better idea to solving issue!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It is not a code stuff. I have uploaded an image to cpanel and deleted the old image.But still display the old image that i deleted

Comment: "It is not a code stuff." Then it's really not a question suited to stackoverflow. Perhaps you should ask using the forum at the hosting site.